# Entity framework MVC

Tags: .net, mvc

Estoy incursionando en este tema pero al hacer ejemplo sencillo sale una excepcion que no he podido resolver,
Primero generé una tabla sencilla para el ejercicio

**1. Script de creacion de tabla en sql server**

```
create table prueba
  (
  Code int not null,
  Descrip varchar(25)
   CONSTRAINT [PK_prueba] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Code] ASC
))
```

**2. creacion de la entidad**

[Table("prueba")]
public class PruebaDto
{
[Key]
public  int Code { get; set; }
public string Descrip { get; set; }
}

**3. adiciono la nueva entidad en el modelo**

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
modelBuilder.Ignore<ExtensionDataObject>();
modelBuilder.Entity<PruebaDto>().ToTable("prueba");
modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("dbo");
}
```

**4. ingreso el objeto registro a la tabla pero ahi es donde falla
InnerException = {"Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Code', table 'dbo.prueba'; column does not allow nulls.} **

```
PruebaDto registro = new PruebaDto();
 registro.Code = 4; 
 registro.Descrip = "naranjas";
  context.Set<PruebaDto>().Add(registro);
  context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Todo el código debe ir como texto no como imagen, de esta forma yo puedo copiar y pegar tu código para intentar replicar tu problema.